# Десериализация части строки

Tags: c#, .net, сериализация

Я получаю такой ответ от get запроса:

```
{"languages":[{"code":"bg","translatedName":"Bulgarian"},
{"code":"cn","translatedName":"Chinese"},
{"code":"cs","translatedName":"Czech"},
"paging":{"itemsCount":18,"pageCount":1,"itemsPerPage":18,"currentPage":0}}
```

Как я могу десериализовать только *languages* как `List<LanguageModel>`?

```
public class LanguageModel
{
            public string Code { get; set; } = null!;
    
            public string TranslatedName { get; set; } = null!;

}
```

Comment: Мне надо полностью игнорировать второй класс. Меня интересует только languages

Comment: JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<LanguageModel>>(jsonResult) не работает для меня

Comment: У вас в примере ошибка, то что есть открывающий тег `[` но нет закрывающего ?

Comment: @veksela Ну вы для начала дайте JSON валидный, ибо сейчас он у вас с ошибкой от которой зависит вся суть данного вопроса, ибо если у вас `[` закрывается после последнего языка (`"Czech"}]`), то ответ в дубликате, если же у вас "закрывашка" после объекта `paging` (что вряд-ли, ибо `[]` это массив объектов и там не может быть просто так таких данных), то ответ тогда чуть будет другим, да.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не хватает корневого объекта, где будет лежать `languages`

```
public class RootModel
{
  public LanguageModel[] Languages { get; set; } 
}
public class LanguageModel
{
   public string Code { get; set; }  
   public string TranslatedName { get; set; }
}
```

Применение `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootModel>(jsonResult)`